# can't push file to system/bin using adb in android 5.1

Tags: root-access, file-system, linux

Using `adb push` file to `/system/bin` return read-only file permission

If i changed mode returns the same error

I'm trying to `push su` to `/system/bin`, why it fails on 5.1, and seems to work on older versions (based on reading through forums)?

Comment: You can't write to a /system directory without root permissions. Lollipop devices in general cannot be rooted in this way due to Android permissions. Although you didn't state the device it is best to use a standard rooting method of custom recovery and flashing the SuperSU ZIP installation file.

Comment: @acejavelin i will try